# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows while writing data to Hbase through spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write the data to Hbase through spark dataframe

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val warehouseLocation = new File("warehouse").getAbsolutePath

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark Hive").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()


    val config = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "zookeeperIP address")
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
    config.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "june_poc_hbase_table")

    val newAPIJobConfiguration1 = Job.getInstance(config)
    newAPIJobConfiguration1.getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, "june_poc_hbase_table")
    newAPIJobConfiguration1.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TableOutputFormat[ImmutableBytesWritable]])
    import spark.implicits._
    val df: DataFrame = Seq(("foo", "1", "foo1"), ("bar", "2", "bar1")).toDF("key", "value1", "value2")

    val hbasePuts = df.rdd.map((row: Row) => {
      val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(0)))
      put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("value1"), Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(1)))
      put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf2"), Bytes.toBytes("value2"), Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(2)))
      (new ImmutableBytesWritable(), put)
    })
    hbasePuts.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(newAPIJobConfiguration1.getConfiguration())
  }
```

Error:

```
19/06/06 09:09:37 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, or1hdp276.corp.adobe.com, executor 2): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1405)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: june_poc_hbase_table: 1 time,
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.makeException(AsyncProcess.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.access$2000(AsyncProcess.java:238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForAllPreviousOpsAndReset(AsyncProcess.java:1817)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:246)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.close(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.close(TableOutputFormat.java:120)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil.closeWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:139)
        ... 10 more
```

Comment: Any update on this problem? We also have this issue and I assume that it is caused by huge compaction queue size of HBase region servers. The jobs we were running are very similar and this problem occurs right after extreme high growth of compaction queue. I did not find any solution yet.